# post variable in include file causes an undefined index error - why?

Tags: php

I have the following line of code in a php include() file:

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
```

This causes an undefined index error.  Is this never allowed in an include() file?  Thanks!

To clarify, I have an check-login file, and an include file.  In the include file is the line:

```
$code = $_POST['code'];
```

The index file has a line:

```
<tr><td><input name="code" type="text" autofocus></td></tr>
```

And in the check-login, I have the lines:

```
if ($code == "abcd") {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['code'] = $code;
    header("location:list.php");
}
```

So now once the correct code is entered at the index page, the user will successfully get to the appropriate destination, but that 'undefined index' error will pop, regarding the
    $code = $_POST['code'];

Thanks again.

Comment: So, basically you have a file inc.php with your given code and it is included in main.php (say) and you're making a post request to main.php. Is that what you are saying ?

Comment: ^ See thats the problem @Mark, we're guessing here. We really need to see all the details to make an informed diagnosis

Comment: Most likely a scope issue. You need to show full code and how it's being used, including where its origin's variable is taken "from". As it stands, your question falls within two categories, unclear what you're asking and it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem; I chose the latter.

Comment: Sorry about that, let me edit the question to provide more clarity.

Comment: Consult my answer below @Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have posted, I have been able to successfully test the following using my implementation/interpretation of your code.

You may have omitted the `<form></form>` tags, I can't be 100% since it's not shown in your question.

The following produced a successful result. If `abcd` is entered, it will echo `OK`.

Otherwise it will echo `Sorry`.

***Sidenote:*** I recommend you not place `session_start();` where you presently have it, since it will throw an error of headers already sent.

Place it beneath your opening `<?php` tag if possible or place `ob_start();` under your opening `<?php` tag if you are going to keep `session_start();` where it presently is.

PHP

```
<?php

include 'included_file.php';

    if(!empty($_POST['code'])){
    if ($code == "abcd") {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['code'] = $code;

    // header("location:list.php");

     // my own test - remove once using header above
    echo "OK";

    }

    else{
    echo "Sorry";
    }

} // brace for if(!empty($_POST['code']))

?>

<tr><td>
<form method="post" action="">
<input name="code" type="text">
</form>
</td></tr>
```

(included_file.php)

```
<?php
$code = $_POST['code'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along these lines of code :

```
    $code = '';

    $issetCode = isset( $_POST['code'] ) ? true : false ;

    if( ! $issetCode or ( $code = trim( $_POST['code'] ) ) == '' )
    {
        if( $issetCode ) echo 'Please enter code<br>';
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input name="code" type="text" autofocus>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        if( $code == "abcd" )
        {
            session_start( );
            $_SESSION['code'] = $code;
            header( "location:list.php" );
        }
        else
        {
            // Invalid code !
        }
    }
```